# Increase Faith and Takkwal

Tags: quran, dua

I read that to increase faith and make dua the most of it, is to read quran everyday which makes sense. But does reading one Ayah a day from the Quran count?

Comment: What is Takkwal?

Answer (score 0):

A single verse of the Quran is powerful enough to increase your Eeman. A single mention of Almighty Allah is potent enough to elevate you. Never underestimate the power of returning to Allah.